# postgres issues with role trying to create a new database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Being a newbie to postgres. I'm a little confused on roles and why I am unable to create a database under that role which clearly shows that the role has "Create DB" attribute.

For example there is an existing role name "MAS" in the system that can create a DB.

```
postgres=> \du
                                                      List of roles
       Role name        |                   Attributes                   |                   Member of
------------------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------
 MAS                    | Create role, Create DB                        +| {rds_superuser,abc_user,def_user,biuser}
                        | Password valid until infinity                  |
```

Using psql, I am able to login to the database from the command line like so:

```
psql -h mas.myserver.com -p 5432 -U MAS postgres
```

Now, I want create the database using this: "CreateDB.sql'

```
CREATE DATABASE mas_dev_123
  WITH OWNER = MAS
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
       LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

postgres=> \i CreateDB.sql
psql:CreateDB.sql:11: ERROR:  role "mas" does not exist
```

Its clear using `\du`, that my role `MAS` exists. So, what am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `WITH OWNER = "MAS"`. It looks like you are having a case mismatch.

Comment: @Politank-Z - Giving you credit for this. Using a double quote did the the trick. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS